# Getting text from JCaptcha image with OpenCV and pytesseract

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

I'm trying to solve a captcha that it looks it's from a library called JCaptcha. The original image is:

[Captcha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FbWW.png)

I use PlayWright and I get an screenshot from the captcha image and it ends looking like this:

["Grey"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ez21.png)

I'm showing this process because it looks the color of the image changes when I make the screenshot with playwright:

```
await page.get_by_role("img", name="Captcha").screenshot(path="captcha.png")
```

Next.

I tried different settings and 135 treshold looks good:

```
img = cv.imread('captcha.png', 0)
th = cv.threshold(img, 135, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

Result:
[Black/White](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxxyQ.png)

From here I invert:

```
invert = (255-th)
```

[Inverted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTkNo.png)

Trying to get the text:

```
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(invert, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
print(data)
```

Result:
s 19]

I know there is a lot of work to do, so I hope you could help me to go through the right direction.

Tried to remove noise but still does not work:

```
kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (1,1))
clean = cv.morphologyEx(th, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
```